# Removing vowels and special characters while captilizing consonants using recursion only in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function that deletes vowels, special characters, and spaces from a phrase and capitalizes the consonants. I'm having trouble thinking up a purely recursive function. Also not sure how to chain functions in C++. Is it possible to use `toUpperCase()` and `isalpha()` together? Is there a way to combine the two conditions in the `else if` clauses and place them in the `else` clause?

```
bool isVowel(char ch) {

        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' ||
            ch == 'O' || ch == 'U' || ch == 'Y') {
        return true;
    }
        else {
        return false;
    }
}

string onlyConnectize(string phrase) {        

        phrase = toUpperCase(phrase);

        // base case
        if (phrase.empty()) {
        return "";
    }
        else if (!isalpha(phrase[0])) {
        return "";
    }
        else if (isVowel(phrase[0])) {
        return "";
    }
        else {
        return phrase[0] + onlyConnectize(phrase.substr(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that if `isalpha(ch)` is `false` then the `isConsonant` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) actually returns an `int`. Check if it returns a valid character value and cast it to `char`. You can't add `std::string` to an `int` but you can add an `std::string` to a `char`. I think it can only return a non-`char` value if you call it with `EOF` instead of a `char` (it's argument is also an `int`).

Comment: Why are you return `int`s from functions that are supposed to return a `string`?

Comment: 1) why does the `capConsonant` return 0 when `phrase` is empty? Similarly, if it is not consonant you return 0 again. There are many places you return it as 0. Be careful with that. 2) you call toUpperCase `n` times, where `n` is the length of the string. You may want to call it only once.